# How do I make tabs for a ViewPager now that ActionBar tabs are deprecated (Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I've seen that `PagerTabStrip` is a method of displaying tabs for a `ViewPager`. And now that `ActionBar` has been deprecated for `Toolbar`, it seems that the `PagerTabStrip` is my only option.

Except, I only see it comes out in the following style:
[image]

I really just want normal tabs (with icons) the way I could do it with the ActionBar before like this:

[image]

What is the proper way of doing this now? Should I use an old `TabWidget` and add tabs manually? Or is there a way of styling the `PagerTabStrip` that I didn't know about?

EDIT: Here's the library I ended up using: https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs

Comment: There are independent indicators, such as the ViewPagerIndicator library, `PagerSlidingTabStrip`, and others, available as open source projects. You can also write your own indicator.

Comment: Is the action bar really deprecated?

Comment: Thanks for the link; I looked through that post before but didn't seem to find quite the right answer. I updated my question with an example of the result I'm going for. Unfortunately `PagerTabStrip` only seems to show the short strip with text to the far sides

Comment: @Prodikl   I have been struggling with this same UX question.  I have yet to find a good answer :(

Comment: @AG1 hey, here's the library i ended up using: https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs

Comment: @Prodikl  I ended up hacking mine together from the high-level overview in this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803835/slidingtablayout-to-fit-the-screen   The backwards compatibility team at Google should provide this functionality in a library, I spent ~3 hours tweaking mine to work the way I wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [SlidingTabLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java) from [Google I/O Android App](https://github.com/google/iosched). It depends on [SlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java).

You can see how it's used by doing a [simple search](https://github.com/google/iosched/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=SlidingTabLayout): you add it to your layout and then just connect it with your `ViewPager` like so:

```
slidingTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
```

There is a way to `setCustomTabView` to customize the tabs.

Comment: Thanks for that. That doesn't seem quite what I'm looking for. Ideally I'd be able to just add icons to tabs. I've updated my original question with an image example of what I'm looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: Does this solution play nice with Toolbar?