# Tab not taking full width on Tablet device [Using android.support.design.widget.TabLayout]

Tags: android, tabs, width, android-appcompat, android-tablayout

I have setup tabs as **UPDATE 29/05/2015** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540078/use-tab-with-new-toolbar-appcompat-v7-21) post. Tabs take full width on my Nexus 4 mobile but on nexus 7 tablet it in center and not cover full screen width.

**Nexus 7 screenshot**
[image: Nexus7]
**Nexus 4 screenshot**
[image: Nexus 4]

Comment: was struggling with exact same issue for 6 hours, but I didn't realize it has issue with tabs only... think on stackoverflow there should be functionality to upvote a question 10 times...

Comment: please try to add more tags to questions... (so will be more helpful for people like me), because this question I found on third page of my google search list

Answer (score 685, accepted):

A "simpler" answer [borrowed from Kaizie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31188097/1438339) would just be adding `app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"` in your `TabLayout` xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Comment: What if I need it to be scrollable? Changing tabMode to support scroll breaks this solution.

Comment: Any solution for scrollable?

Comment: Hi.. I have tried adding this. but the single tab is not taking entire width of the tab layout.

Comment: app:tabMaxWidth="0dp" works for me, and that also without using  app:tabMode="fixed"

Comment: This solution also works if the tabMode is not set. The scrollable tapMode doesn't appear to support the features of filled gravity and 0dp max width.

Comment: This worked for me! I had tabGravity=fill and tabmode=fixed and as it is mentioned in the answer, setting tabMaxWidth=0dp did the trick for me! I had to do this for nexus 9.

Comment: Why does it occur though? Is it the default behavior? Or something I didn't use well ? Is it a part of the guidelines to set the tabs in the middle? This doesn't occur for me when using 3+ tabs. Only for 2 tabs.

Comment: this fixed a problem for me in landscape mode (even though it was working fine in portrait)

Comment: I used `ConstraintLayout` as root. To get the full width just add *app:tabGravity="fill"*. And it's working. tabMaxWidth doesn't work for me

Comment: @androiddeveloper did you ever find out why this only happens with two tabs specifically?

Comment: is there a way to set app:tabMaxWidth programmatically?

Comment: What does [Material Design](https://material.io/design) have to say about this `tabMaxWidth` setting? Should we really set it to `0dp`? Though, the default value of `264dp` is certainly too low for larger screens.

Answer (score 101):

I had the same problem and I checked the TabLayout style, and i found that its default style is `Widget.Design.TabLayout` which has different implementations (normal, landscape and sw600dp).

The one we need is the one for tablets (sw600dp) which has the following implementation:

```
<style name="Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabGravity">center</item>
        <item name="tabMode">fixed</item>
 </style>
```

From this style we will use "*tabGravity*" (which possible values are "center" or "fill") using the "fill" value.

But we need to go deeper, and then we see that this one extends from `Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout`, which implementation is:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="tabMaxWidth">@dimen/tab_max_width</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Tab</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

So, from this style we will need to override "*tabMaxWidth*".
In my case I set it to `0dp`, so it has no limit.

And my style looked like this:

```
<style name="MyTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabGravity">fill</item>
        <item name="tabMaxWidth">0dp</item>
</style>
```

And then the tab bar will fill the whole screen from side to side.

Comment: nice discovery.. going to the root. But please highlight the exact answer at top, it will be easier to find someone who don't want to read all the answer

Comment: great solution, weird how the api looks like you can control it without changing the underlying style. Looks like tabMaxWidth is the true culprit

Comment: This is like an episode of Sherlock. Thank you!!

Answer (score 32):

Solution for scrollable: (TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE), that is when ever you need  more than 2 tabs (Dynamic tabs)

Step 1 : style.xml

```
<style name="tabCustomStyle" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
            <item name="tabGravity">fill</item>
            <item name="tabMaxWidth">0dp</item>
            <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#FFFEEFC4</item>
            <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
            <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
            <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">#FFFEEFC4</item>
        </style>

        <style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
            <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/tab_text_size</item>
            <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.roboto_medium</item>
            <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
        </style>
        <style name="TextAppearance.roboto_medium" parent="android:TextAppearance">
            <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-medium</item>
        </style>
```

Step 2 : Your xml layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            style="@style/tabCustomStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_strip_height"
            android:background="@color/your_color"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/your_color" />
```

Step 3: In your Activity/Fragment where ever you have tabs.

```
/**
     * To allow equal width for each tab, while (TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE)
     */
    private void allotEachTabWithEqualWidth() {

        ViewGroup slidingTabStrip = (ViewGroup) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            View tab = slidingTabStrip.getChildAt(i);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) tab.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.weight = 1;
            tab.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This worked only with more than 1 tab, if we have only one tab the tab don't fill the tab-layout. To solve that issue i added             app:tabMaxWidth="1000dp" and it worked.

Comment: This worked best for me.  In my custom tab layout class, I overrode `addTab` and set the weight for each tab as it was added.

`override fun addTab(tab: Tab, position: Int, setSelected: Boolean) {
        super.addTab(tab, position, setSelected)
        allotEachTabWithEqualWidth()
    }`

Answer (score 14):

To force tabs to take up the full width (split into equal sizes), apply the following to the `TabLayout` view:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_tab_layout);
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
```

Comment: Just letting folks know, this does not work with if your `TabLayout` is set to `app:tabMode=“scrollable”`, it will result in the tabs becoming fixed length (long words will wrap) and the tabs will no longer slide, essentially making the tabs “fixed” again.

Answer (score 8):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

work for me. This also have `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Answer (score 6):

This is helpful you must try

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/orange" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Just did this and worked like a charm

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

For me the following code worked and was enough.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Solution for Scrollable (Kotlin)**

***In xml:***

```
     <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:tabGravity="fill" />
```

***In Kotlin:***

In my case if less than 3 tabs I allocate equal space.

**Note: If condition is as per your requirement**

```
        if(list.size <= 3){
          allotEachTabWithEqualWidth(your_tab_layout)
        }

     fun allotEachTabWithEqualWidth(tabLayout: TabLayout) {
        tabLayout.tabMode=  TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE
        val slidingTabStrip = tabLayout.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
        for (i in 0 until tabLayout.getTabCount()) {
            val tab = slidingTabStrip.getChildAt(i)
            val layoutParams = tab.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            layoutParams.weight = 1f
            tab.layoutParams = layoutParams
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check below code for solutions.

Below is layout code:

```
<com.yourpackage.CustomTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/off_white"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/primaryColor"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="0dp" />
```

Note, for dynamic tab count, don't forget to call setTabNumbers(tabcount).

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout
{
    private static final int WIDTH_INDEX = 0;
    private int DIVIDER_FACTOR = 3;
    private static final String SCROLLABLE_TAB_MIN_WIDTH = "mScrollableTabMinWidth";

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initTabMinWidth();
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initTabMinWidth();
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initTabMinWidth();
    }

    public void setTabNumbers(int num)
    {
        this.DIVIDER_FACTOR = num;
        initTabMinWidth();
    }

    private void initTabMinWidth()
    {
        int[] wh = getScreenSize(getContext());
        int tabMinWidth = wh[WIDTH_INDEX] / DIVIDER_FACTOR;

        Log.v("CUSTOM TAB LAYOUT", "SCREEN WIDTH = " + wh[WIDTH_INDEX] + " && tabTotalWidth = " + (tabMinWidth*DIVIDER_FACTOR) + " && TotalTabs = " + DIVIDER_FACTOR);

        Field field;
        try {
            field = TabLayout.class.getDeclaredField(SCROLLABLE_TAB_MIN_WIDTH);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(this, tabMinWidth);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final int WIDTH_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int HEIGHT_INDEX = 1;

    public static int[] getScreenSize(Context context) {
        int[] widthHeight = new int[2];
        widthHeight[WIDTH_INDEX] = 0;
        widthHeight[HEIGHT_INDEX] = 0;

        try {
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            widthHeight[WIDTH_INDEX] = size.x;
            widthHeight[HEIGHT_INDEX] = size.y;

            if (!isScreenSizeRetrieved(widthHeight))
            {
                DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                display.getMetrics(metrics);
                widthHeight[0] = metrics.widthPixels;
                widthHeight[1] = metrics.heightPixels;
            }

            // Last defense. Use deprecated API that was introduced in lower than API 13
            if (!isScreenSizeRetrieved(widthHeight)) {
                widthHeight[0] = display.getWidth(); // deprecated
                widthHeight[1] = display.getHeight(); // deprecated
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return widthHeight;
    }

    private static boolean isScreenSizeRetrieved(int[] widthHeight) {
        return widthHeight[WIDTH_INDEX] != 0 && widthHeight[HEIGHT_INDEX] != 0;
    }
}
```

Reference taken from https://medium.com/@elsenovraditya/set-tab-minimum-width-of-scrollable-tablayout-programmatically-8146d6101efe

Answer (score 1):

Why all that hectic work ? 
Just put `app:tabMode="scrollable"` in your TabLayout in XML.
Thats it.

[image]

Comment: What if there is 3 tab? that won't fit to screen (tabs are dynamic that are coming from server API) tabs count known at run time..

Comment: Then you can even set programmatically like this `tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);` Also this is just a property to set for tabLayout this never matter how many tabs you are adding either static or dynamic.

Comment: It will make tab width according to text size.Check my edited answer with image.

Comment: Ya in that case tab mode is SCROLLABLE  then at the end u will see empty space thats look odd

Answer (score 1):

In my variant of this problem, I had 3 tabs of moderate size which weren't taking up full width on tablets. I didn't need the tabs to be scrollable on tablets, since tablets are big enough to display the tabs all together without any scrolling. But I did need the tabs to be scrollable on phones, since phones are too small to display all the tabs together.

The best solution in my case was to add a `res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml` file, where the relevant TabLayout could have `app:tabGravity="fill"` and `app:tabMode="fixed"`. But in my regular `res/layout/main_activity.xml`, I left out `app:tabGravity="fill"` and `app:tabMode="fixed"`, and had `app:tabMode="scrollable"` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that you also need to set

```
  app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
  app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
```

to fill all space

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]. This is a question and answer site, not a discussion forum. This section is only for complete answers. Once you have earned 50 reputation points by asking and answering you will be able to [comment on other users' questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).