# android Tab Layout Design Library

Tags: android, tabs

I am using TabLayout from new android.support.design.widget package.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

But on tablets they looks like

[image]

How to stretch them to fill full width. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Taken the answer from 
[Tab not taking full width on Tablet device [Using android.support.design.widget.TabLayout]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843775/tab-not-taking-full-width-on-tablet-device-using-android-support-design-widget)

Credit goes to Kaizie

Implement your own TabLayoutStyle like this

```
<style name="MyTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabGravity">fill</item>
        <item name="tabMaxWidth">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me. I'm sorry, that I did not see that post.