# How to make TabLayout take up full width of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles, android-tablayout

My tabs on the `TabLayout` occupy the centre of the screen and are not filling the entire width even after adding `tabMaxWidth = "0dp"` as per [Adam John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31620690/6527796)

That is I want by tabs to extend to fill screen like this:

[image]

But what I get is this:

[image]

My XML looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tl_contact_type"
            style="@style/tabWidgetLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"/>
```

style.xml for `tabWidgetLayout`

```
<style name="tabWidgetLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
            <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/colorTealAccent</item>
            <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">@dimen/default_corner_radius_medium</item>
            <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
            <item name="android:background">@color/colorBrandPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/color_tab_selected_text</item>
            <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/tabWidgetLayoutTextAppearance</item>
        </style>
```

Any help to fix this is much appreciated.

Comment: from screenshot it seems like you are running it on a Tablet. Give it a try on a normal android phone

Comment: @VivekMishra Thanks for your suggestion. However, those were stock images, I only added them to emphasise on how my layout is rendered. I've been trying on normal android phone (HTC) all along and the tabs doesn't take up the full width.

Comment: And removing `maxWidth` still leaves it the same?

Comment: can you post `tabWidgetLayout` your `style` in the question ??

Comment: @Vucko Yes. Still leaves the same.

Comment: @Ironman just added an edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try below snippet

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

Tell me this sloved your issue or not.

Happy to help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But it didn't solve the issue. This was my initial layout to start with. And as per link I attached to the question, I added `tabMaxWidth` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Worth looking at @style/tabWidgetLayout and its parent layout for padding and margin values.

Comment: I revisited my app that uses tab layout. Looks like this is a default behaviour of tabs. On my phone, tab occupies the whole width on portrait but does not on landscape. Have you tried running on sw600?

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/ColorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/ColorPrimary"
            app:tabTextColor="#000"
            app:tabBackground="@color/cardview_light_background"/>
```

Replace your code with this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not extending the `android:Widget`
Try adding this to your `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/tab_background</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

EDIT:
This I found long time ago in another question (which I can't remember) and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Change  `android:layout_width="match_parent"` or set a custom size on this  attribute

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewTab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```