# Increase gap between Tab and TabLayout

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want to increase gap between tab and tablayout.
Now i have this.Check image. I try method margin and padding but i cannot solve it..I want such as padding bottom [image]

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Fragments.MainFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
            style="@style/MyTabLayout"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabPaddingStart="30dp"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="30dp"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
   
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please check this solution [https://stackoverflow.com/a/31620690/9633290] hope this will work for you

Comment: there is a app:tabPaddingTop did you tried that one ?

Comment: @AgentP yes but doesnt work

Comment: Have you created your own custom view for tab item ?

Comment: @AgentP yes..i have custom

Comment: Please post that custom view code as well